# Handle exceptions over class library without Try Catch

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I am working with ASP.NET MVC 4, .Net 4.5, Windows Azure. I handled all exceptions with out writing try catch blocks in Frontier(Web Application) using **OnException()** controller base class method. I am thinking to handle all exceptions in middle layers(BLL, DAL) in similar fashion without writing try catch blocks, because million lines of code already done without exception handling. Is this possible ? looking for suggestions.

Comment: Nothing is impossible. How you handle the situation its all depend upon you .

Comment: Why do you want to handle all esceptions in your BLL and DAL? In general, you should just let exceptions bubble up.

Comment: The common way to handle top level exceptions in ASP.NET is using the `Application_Error` event. This will also catch all exceptions from non-controller requests as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i got solution from MSDN forums. following link is enough to do  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx

Comment: Please make sure it is feasible in MVC web application.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of Exception Handling Frameworks which can intercept exceptions and perform various tasks (log them, send a notification mail etc...)

[ELMAH](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/) is a good option for your web application though it sounds like you have that side covered.

You could also look at the [Microsoft Patterns & Practices Enterprise Library](http://entlib.codeplex.com/) [Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649552.aspx) & [Logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647183.aspx) Blocks

In general though, it's good practice to bubble your exceptions back to the highest calling application block and let it take care of application logging in one place.

Comment: could you please give some bubbling exception ways ?